# implementation of Enumerator::Product for ruby pre 3.2

Tags: ruby

Cartesian product of enumerator has been included in the latest ruby core since version 3.2 with class [Enumerator::Product](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Enumerator/Product.html).

My question is regading it's best (performance, memory, overhead, ...) implementation in previous releases of ruby.

More precisely my question is essentially on comparing the left and right recursion version.

```
def left_cartesian_product((*f, e))
  Enumerator.new do |y|
    if e.nil?
      y << []
    else
      left_cartesian_product(f).each { |u|
        e.each { |x|
          y << [*u, x]
        }
      }
    end
  end
end
```

```
def right_cartesian_product((e, *f))
  Enumerator.new do |y|
    if e.nil?
      y << []
    else
      e.each { |x|
        right_cartesian_product(f).each { |u|
          y << [x, *u]
        }
      }
    end
  end
end
```

```
# usage sample
xxxx_cartesian_product(['a'..'h', 1..8]).each { |c, r| puts "%s%d" % [c,r] }
```

If ever there are more clever way of implementing it I'm also interested, with less overhead, less  code, ...
I kept an array for both cases in parameters list because left case wouldn't behave nicely with (*f, e= nil) and keep claiming at least one parameter.

Comment: I've installed ruby-prof gem to perform some profiling. But not knowing the behind the hook of ruby, it's hard to say why it's behave like that.
with my tests left recursion is faster (twice) but took more memory (twice) as the right version.
there indeed should be a theoritical explanation, but I'm looking for someone that could explain why.

Also i was surprized with a third implementation which is using Array.product, that outperforms both in memery and cpu usage the previous ones. but it shouldn't for memory.

Comment: Maybe your question is more suitable for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: stackoverflow as stated in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic are for programmation (including algorithms of course). if my question isn't a specific programming question what is it?

Comment: Sure, I didn't say that it's off-topic, merely that Code Review might be more suitable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right one is slow because it's initializing a lot more of `Enumerator` objects:

```rb
def recursive_right((e, *f))
  Enumerator.new do |y|
    puts "right - new enumerator"
    if e.nil?
      y << []
    else
      e.each { |x|
        recursive_right(f).each { |u|
          y << [x, *u]
        }
      }
    end
  end
end

def recursive_left((*f, e))
  Enumerator.new do |y|
    puts "left - new enumerator"
    if e.nil?
      y << []
    else
      recursive_left(f).each { |u|
        e.each { |x|
          y << [*u, x]
        }
      }
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
input = ["a".."c", [1, 2, 3]]
recursive_left(input).to_a
recursive_right(input).to_a

# =>
# left - new enumerator
# left - new enumerator
# left - new enumerator
# right - new enumerator
# right - new enumerator
# right - new enumerator
# right - new enumerator
# right - new enumerator
# right - new enumerator
# right - new enumerator
# right - new enumerator
# right - new enumerator
# right - new enumerator
# right - new enumerator
# right - new enumerator
# right - new enumerator
```

---

Ideally you should only initialize one:

```rb
def enum_product(args, m = [], &)
  first, *rest = args
  unless first
    yield m
    return
  end
  first.each do |i|
    enum_product(rest, m + [i], &)
  end
end

def product(*args)
  Enumerator.new do |y|
    puts "product - new enumerator"
    enum_product(args) do |enum|
      y << enum
    end
  end
end

input = ["a".."c", [1, 2, 3]]
product(*input).to_a
# =>
# product - new enumerator
# [["a", 1], ["a", 2], ["a", 3], ["b", 1], ["b", 2], ["b", 3], ["c", 1], ["c", 2], ["c", 3]]
```

Or use `Enumerable`:

```rb
class Product
  include Enumerable

  def initialize(*args)
    @args = args
  end

  def each
    enum_product(@args) do |enum|
      yield enum
    end
  end

  private

  def enum_product(args, m = [], &)
    first, *rest = args
    unless first
      yield m
      return
    end
    first.each do |i|
      enum_product(rest, m + [i], &)
    end
  end
end
```

---

Here is a little benchmark:

```rb
input    = ["a".."c", [1, 2, 3], :x..:z]
expected = Enumerator::Product.new(*input).to_a
puts "Test:"
p recursive_left(input).to_a  == expected
p recursive_right(input).to_a == expected
p product(*input).to_a        == expected
p Product.new(*input).to_a    == expected

require "benchmark"
n = 100_000
Benchmark.bmbm(10) do |x|
  x.report(:right)   { n.times { recursive_right(input).to_a } }
  x.report(:left)    { n.times { recursive_left(input).to_a } }
  x.report(:product) { n.times { product(*input).to_a } }
  x.report(:Product) { n.times { Product.new(*input).to_a } }
end
```

```rb
Test:
true
true
true
true
Rehearsal ----------------------------------------------
right       16.247681   0.044432  16.292113 ( 16.301701)
left         4.062121   0.004015   4.066136 (  4.068666)
product      3.086748   0.012002   3.098750 (  3.100267)
Product      2.399628   0.004009   2.403637 (  2.404921)
------------------------------------ total: 25.860636sec

                 user     system      total        real
right       16.419361   0.039966  16.459327 ( 16.470319)
left         3.988729   0.011989   4.000718 (  4.002679)
product      3.098028   0.003985   3.102013 (  3.104423)
Product      2.364256   0.007983   2.372239 (  2.373399)
```

Comment: thank you, the product_enum that terminally yield each tuplet is indeed better with only one Enumerator wrapper. I'm also surprized that class version performs better than simple top method definitions.